# ejs express nodejs onclick show details

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

i built up a nodejs app using express and ejs as template engine. i can show a list of articles in a page but i don't know how to show detail of article when i click on the item. using Angular 4 you can use components and inject componets on the same page showing details in one compement when you click the item in the other one. i was wondering if it is possible to achieve same goal with ejs

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
      <% items.forEach(item){%>
         <ul>
             <li><%=item%></li>
         </ul>
      <% } %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8>[here details of article]</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright so , each item is an article ? With other words you need to access the details of each item ?

Comment: correct. i want to add an onclick event and show in the other div the details of the item/article

Comment: Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: I am very new to this scripting also though I think I see a solution here. Move the div inside the Script I mean before the final <%} %> but not inside the for loop . Make a local variable that is holding a reference to the item and add an event listener. After all it is Javascript.